# Powershell email received from local machine but not from server

Tags: email, powershell

I wrote a script to update, build and publish some code. After the build it will send an email with the build log. When I run the script from my local machine, I can get the email in my work email box. When I run the script from the server I can only get the email to my personal email address. I don't get any errors when running the script.

I have -SmtpServer "localhost" and -Port "25".

I'm not seeing any other posts anywhere where people aren't getting an error of some sort. Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

There is a good chance your Corp email has some sort of white-list IP address/SPF. When you send it from your local machine, you are using your office network, and the IP is already white listed. When you running it on the server, it could be on a remote location/cloud or using a different public IP and email gets blocked due to the unknown source.

Comment: I work remote and the corporate office is several states away. I don't believe I'm on the office network.

Comment: Is your local SMTP server configured differently?

Comment: on my local machine i'm using mail.twc.com and port 587, per timewarner's website. on the server i was told to use localhost and port 25.

Comment: This is not a code problem, emails relayed out from your side, you will need to see the smtp logs on the vendor side to see what the problem is. Still, it is most likely gets blocked by recipient somehow.

Answer (score 0):

This was an smtp issue. For some reason it did not like the sending ip address.

Unfortunately PowerShell wasn't giving me any errors. I had to look in the smtp logs and found that the ip address was being blocked.

`Access+denied,+banned+sending+IP+[xx.xx.xxx.xx]`

On the same line there were instructions on how to fix the issue.

`To+request+removal+from+this+list+please+visit+https://sender.office.com/+and+follow+the+directions.`

I followed the instructions and it fixed the blocking of the ip address.

NOTE: The last step of this process says it could take up to 30 minutes to take affect, but it took a lot longer for the issue to be fixed for me.

I hope this helps someone.